# How to prevent type from being used as a member variable type in a struct/class?

Tags: c++, types, member

I want to create type that can be used only as a complete type, not as a member variable type.

So this shall be allowed for such `T` type:

```
T a;
^^^
int foo(T b);
        ^^^
struct C { int foo(T b); };
                   ^^^
int main() { T c; }
             ^^^
```

But this shall cause compile time error:

```
struct C { T a; };
           ^^^
```

I would like very much to present anything I tried so far, but there is nothing which can be at least close to solution I need, sorry for that.

**Of course, I also accept answer proving this is not possible in C++.**

Why do I need this? I want to have `smart pointer` which cannot be an element of another object. A poor way to prevent circular dependencies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. From C++ grammar (emphasis is mine, not relevant parts are omitted for clarity) the declaration for a function is:

`function-definition:

decl-specifier-seqopt declarator ctor-initializeropt function-body

decl-specifier-seqopt declarator function-try-block`

For a class it is:

`class-specifier:

class-head { member-specificationopt }



member-specification:

member-declaration member-specificationopt

access-specifier : member-specificationopt



member-declaration:

decl-specifier-seqopt member-declarator-listopt ;

function-definition ;opt

::opt nested-name-specifier templateopt unqualified-id ;

using-declaration

template-declaration

member-declarator-list:

member-declarator

member-declarator-list , member-declarator



member-declarator:

declarator pure-specifieropt

declarator constant-initializeropt

identifieropt : constant-expression`

Finally `declarator` is:

`declarator:

direct-declarator

ptr-operator declarator



direct-declarator:

declarator-id

direct-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt
exception-specificationopt

direct-declarator [ constant-expressionopt ]

( declarator )`

As you can see types that can be used for arguments of a function can be used as class members too.

Comment: +! for your effort. However I am doubt this helped me in anyway though.

Comment: @PiotrNycz LOL it just means (from grammar perspective) that what can be used as parameter of a function **can always be used** (besides modifiers) as class member too. It means that you can't prevent a method to store one of its parameters as class member. **Even if you override assignment operator** they can always bypass any type-checking with pointers, aliases and casting. You can control how an object is created (with a factory method, for example) but that's all (and it **won't prevent an object to store a circular reference to itself**).

Answer (score 3):

If you can use an object outside of a class, it can be a member of a class. I'm 99.9% sure that you can't stop that in any way (that doesn't restrict how/where you can use `T` in other ways - clearly having a private constructor would prevent it from being a direct member of a class, but it would also restrict it from being used in the other three scenarios you are showing).

Comment: +! for an idea of private constructor. I will try to follow this concept.